# Creating a GUI based task scheduler in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, timer, jodatime

I have LOG FILES (ie S1Log, S2Log, S3Log etc)  from different SOURCES that I want to upload to a server on a daily basis. The program should upload each log file at a particular time during the day (S1Log at 9AM, S2Log at 3PM, S3Log at 6PM). On some random days, we don't want to follow this schedule, so we prevent some or all of the files from uploading. But, the next day the regular schedule should be followed as usual.

I am not sure about how to schedule these tasks. Would JodaTime be appropriate for this or or should I use java.util.Timer and/or javax.swing.Timer instead?

Is there any other mature and popular API like Joda which can help me to make my code?

Comment: Joda time is not helping you too much here, I think. Look at Quartz. And next time, put the relevant part of your question into the google search box first, (we can call this step "research" as of now), and then ask, if something does not work out...

Comment: @ppeterka - thanks, but I was looking for something simple. Quartz looks so big and complicated. I want to make a desktop app for myself.
http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard java solution for creating a scheduler is using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Executed!");
            return "Called!";
        }
    },
    5,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I would also suggest you to use the **Quartz Scheduler**. Here is a useful tutorial on the same
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-quartz/

Other options you have are a Java Based Timer from **java.util.Timer** and here is a tutorial.
http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-timer/

**But which one to choose... ? Let me make it more difficult for you**

[Pros and cons of using java.util.timer vs Quartz for scheduling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078130/pros-and-cons-of-using-java-util-timer-vs-quartz-for-scheduling)

and

http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz

probably comments can help with that argument..